# If T is maximal theory, do we have $T\models\phi$ iff $ \phi\in T$??

Tags: model-theory

îm new to model theory and Im studing in Marker book.

**My first question** is : If T a maximal that is for every sentence $\phi$ we have either $\phi\in T$ or $\neg\phi \in T$ then for every sentence $\phi$ either $T\models\phi$ or $T\models\neg \phi$.

I think this is true : If $\phi\in T$ then all sentences of are true in every model of T in p1rticular $\phi$, then $\phi$ is a logical consequence of T. And   same thing is true if $\neg\phi\in T$

**My second question** is : If T is maximal do we have : $T\models\phi$ iff $ \phi\in T$??

If $\phi\in T$ by the same previous argument $\phi$ is a logical consequence of T.

If $\phi$ is a logical consequence of T, suppose that $\phi$ is not in T. Then by maximality of T, $\neg\phi$ is in T and hence $T\models\neg\phi$. So we get $T\models\phi$ and $T\models\neg\phi$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2117908) answer your question?

Comment: thank you sir. so the answer to my question is yes?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct and so is your reasoning. If $T \models \varphi$ but $\varphi \not\in T$, then $\lnot \varphi$ would be in $T$, which contradicts the consistency of $T$.

Comment: thank you sir .